# Overriding Storyboard custom colours

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uicolor

I have default custom colours in an xcassets file. I then retrieve an updated set of colours from a server. I override UIColor(named:) to use the updated colours in place of my default set. This works perfectly for UI that's built in code.

However, all Storyboards and Nibs that use custom colours do not get overridden. It seems that iOS doesn't use UIColor(named:) for Storyboards.

Ideally I'd have liked to overwrite the values within Colors.xcassets but believe this isn't possible.

So, is it possible to override the colours in Storyboards?
I realise I can do this by linking views within the Storyboard to references in the view controller, but this is incredibly time consuming and tedious, there has to be a better way?

Comment: As you mentioned, this is probably very time consuming. If you want a modern, dynamic UI builder, you would probably want to switch to SwiftUI 

Comment: @CarlSarkis unfortunately we still have to support iOS 12.

Comment: I don't know your application and your ecosystem, but as more than 95% of the active devices [are using iOS > 14](https://developer.apple.com/fr/support/app-store/) so you may want to discuss the benefits from supporting iOS 12 vs the cost.
Recommandations are usually to support the last 2 versions, 3 if your are brave, 4 is heroic. With iOS 16 it would be 5 versions for you, unless you have a specific enterprise customer with a fleet of very old iPhones you would probably benefit a lot from upgrading to iOS 13 or even 14.